# Why sql "column like 'pattern%'" doesn't use the index?

Tags: mysql, date, query-optimization, where-clause, sql-like

Tried 3 different ways.

**1st**

```
explain select * from test where create_time like '2019-10%';
```

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type|possible_keys       |key|key_len|ref|rows |filtered|Extra      |
--|-----------|-----|----------|----|--------------------|---|-------|---|-----|--------|-----------|
 1|SIMPLE     |test |          |ALL |test_create_time_IDX|   |       |   |10376|   11.11|Using where|
```

**2nd**

```
explain select * from test where create_time between '2019-10-01 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59';
```

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type |possible_keys       |key                 |key_len|ref|rows|filtered|Extra                |
--|-----------|-----|----------|-----|--------------------|--------------------|-------|---|----|--------|---------------------|
 1|SIMPLE     |test |          |range|test_create_time_IDX|test_create_time_IDX|6      |   |   5|     100|Using index condition|
```

**3rd**

```
explain select * from test where date_format(create_time,'%Y-%m') = '2019-10';
```

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows |filtered|Extra      |
--|-----------|-----|----------|----|-------------|---|-------|---|-----|--------|-----------|
 1|SIMPLE     |test |          |ALL |             |   |       |   |10376|     100|Using where|
```

I was told that "like 'pattern%'" will use the index."like '%pattern%'","like '%pattern'" won't.
But on the **1st** condition it didn't work out as i thought.**Is it because the column type of create_time is DATETIME?**
And I can't find details about difference of all these "like" SQLs while interacting with indexes in official reference manual.
**Can somenone pls share a official link with me?**(All I got is hearsay)

Comment: Yes, it's because it's `DATETIME`. It's stored numerically, not as a string, so it first has to convert the date to a string before it can compare it to a `LIKE` pattern.

Comment: This is a duplicate but I'm all out of close votes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101436/mysql-datetime-field-with-index-get-a-range-like-vs-between-and-performance

Comment: You might like to know about this: [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/1115360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [this part of the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html):

> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the `=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, or `BETWEEN` operators. The index also can be used for `LIKE` comparisons if the argument to `LIKE` is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character.

Side note: as [documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), *most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are stored in B-trees*

---

In your examples:

```
create_time like '2019-10%'
```

You are comparing a date to a string. This requires MySQL to convert the data. As you can see in the output of the `explain`, an  index can be used but it will be a full index scan. If `create_time` was a string, the index would be used with a range scan (which is more efficient).

```
create_time between '2019-10-01 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'
```

`between` allows MySQL to optimize the use of index (range scan).

```
date_format(create_time,'%Y-%m') = '2019-10''
```

A function comes into play. The index will not be used.

Comment: *"You are comparing a date to a string. This requires MySQL to convert the data. Because, implicitly, a function comes into play, the index will not be used here. If create_time was a string, the index would be used."* Actually `create_time like '2019-10%'` can use a index but it will be a full index scan..  -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rrTcypcsqrKLV7jBC7P7gQ/3

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes you are correct (actually the OP posted the same explain as you did). I updated my answer, thanks you!

Comment: also the same goes for `date_format` -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rrTcypcsqrKLV7jBC7P7gQ/5  which can also do a index scan..

Comment: But in general you want to indeed make the search condition *"sargable"* which `create_time between '2019-10-01 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'` is  that can use the index much better..